# Retrieve Index of adding a listview item?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, listview, indexing

I use the following code to add a item to my listView...

```
    ListViewItem^ subitem = gcnew ListViewItem();

    subitem->SubItems->Add(textBox2->Text);

    listView3->Items->Add(subitem);
```

What code would I add onto this so it can retrieve the index of this newly added item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of the newly added item should basically be the last index of the collection. Try this :

```
int index = listView3->Items->Count - 1;
```

And also try this :

```
int index = listView3->Items->IndexOf(subitem);
```

Comment: Yes, your second option seems less "hack" and works great, thanks!